# Show output for n commands in parallel

Tags: linux, shell, tmux

Is there a shell command to show the output of n given commands in parallel? I have n log-view commands (where n can be different at the startup time) and I like to show their output in parallel.

It should look like the split view of `tmux`, but with `tmux` it seems to be really hard to just give n commands and get a uniform split output view of them.

The call should be something like (the given commands are probably useless; they are just an example):
`split_command_view "watch -n0.1 ls -la" "tail -F log.txt" "date"`

In this case the screen should be split in three sub-terminals and show the commands outputs.

Does something like this exist?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`multitail` is such a command:

```
multitail -l cmd1 -l cmd2
```

Or if you want the windows to persist after the commands have finished:

```
multitail -l 'cmd1; sleep inf' -l 'cmd2; sleep inf'
```

(if your `sleep` doesn't support `inf`, you can change it to a very large integer instead).

Answer (score 0):

`tail` supports displaying mutiple files at once, however it doesn't split the terminal into panes like `tmux` does.

`tail -f /var/log/syslog /var/log/auth.log`

Comment: I use `kubectl` to show the log of a remote cluster, therefore I think, I cannot use `tail`.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do that is to output the proc to a different TTY.
To know the name of your current tty just type `tty`. It will give you for example `/dev/pts/0`. Then you can run commands like

`tail -f /permanent.log > /dev/pts/0 &`

With the `&` at the end you send the proc to the background so you can run more commands. To recover the proc, you can use the `jobs` and `fg` commands.